Calculating the volume of a body given by $g(x,y,z) = xyz$ using triple integrals
I need help calculating the volume of the region/body/solid given by
$D = \{(x,y,z) \colon 0 \leq xyz \leq 8 \text{ and } 0 \leq x \leq 2, 0 \leq y \leq 2, 0 \leq z \leq 2\}$,
I am supposed to do it with triple integrals, using
$\iiint_{D} 1 dxdydz$,
but I am having a hard time with finding the bounds.

Hint: try to understand what is the domain of integration $D$. The last three inequalities represent a cube of side 2. Does it intersect the curve given by the first set of inequalities?

@rcescon, i really understand. But i did check with desmos 3D-plotting tool, and it seems that the body given by $0 \leq xyz \leq 8$ encapsulates the cube with side length 2. If I zoom so that the axels are on top of the side length of the cube, then it seems that the body given by the first inequality is the cube of side length 2.

If you look at the inequality $0\leq z \leq \frac{8}{xy}$ you can see that as $x,y$ range in the interval $[0,2]$ the fraction is greater than 2 and it equals 2 when both $x,y = 2$. Therefore I would say that the cube is within this inequality which makes the volume equal to 8.

@rcescon, I see. but what about when x or y are 0? I don't really understand why we can conclude that the volume of the body is 8 algebraically/ logically.

If $x\le 2$ then $x y\le 2 y\le 4$ and $x y z\le 4 z \le 8$ because the three numbers are nonnegative, so $0\le x y z \le 8$ is indeed always true.
